# make api call to get json data

Tags: json, node.js, rest

I was trying to get json data from this api, but only thing i'm getting is the html of the page that i would normally get if i opened this link in browser

base url for accessing the api http://sc.productrx.com/public/

**Action:** Get survey table 
**HTTP Verb:** GET 
**Rest Resource:** schema 
 
**Description of parameters, etc:** get schema Table name ("survey")

this is what i have tried so far

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){

   console.log(req.method+" request received at "+req.url);


request({
     url:"https://sc.productrx.com/public/",
     method:"GET",
     qs:{resource:"schema",data_type:"JSON"}
     },function(err,response,body){
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
              res.status(300).json(error.apiError);
            }
          else{
              console.log(body);
              //var body=JSON.parse(body);
              //res.status(200).json({"success":true,"body":body.users});
            }
        });  });
```

this is console log

```
    $ heroku local
[WARN] No ENV file found
11:01:03 AM web.1 |  Your server is now running...
11:01:03 AM web.1 |  5000
11:01:07 AM web.1 |  GET request received at /
11:01:09 AM web.1 |  <!DOCTYPE html>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |  <html>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |      <head>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |          <title>Slim 3</title>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |          <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |          <style>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |              body {
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  padding: 0;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  width: 100%;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  text-align: center;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  color: #aaa;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  font-size: 18px;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |              }
11:01:09 AM web.1 |              h1 {
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  color: #719e40;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  letter-spacing: -3px;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  font-size: 100px;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  font-weight: 200;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                  margin-bottom: 0;
11:01:09 AM web.1 |              }
11:01:09 AM web.1 |          </style>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |      </head>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |      <body>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |          <h1>Slim</h1>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |          <div>a microframework for PHP</div>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |                      <p>Try <a href="http://www.slimframework.com">SlimFramework</a>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |              </body>
11:01:09 AM web.1 |  </html>
```

SOLVED: I was hitting base address of the api, i called them up and they told me the right way to access it. http://sc.productrx.com/public/schema/survey

Comment: With the additional details in the question, i tried the GET request on following API `http://sc.productrx.com/public/schema/survey` and it returns a JSON Array. You are trying to hit the API base, that's why you get the HTML page for `http://sc.productrx.com/public/`

Comment: Yeah, first time with rest api. I found that after a bit of messing. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target URL must data in JSON format. The request library does not convert HTML data to JSON format automatically for you.

For eg. the below URL:
https://www.instagram.com/facebook/?__a=1

returns JSON data from the server.

Comment: correct. the URL you have in the the code is not an API, but just a link to an HTML page.

Comment: thanks. i wish i could +1, but my reputation is too low :(